# How to install zend framework on Ubuntu?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, composer-php

I want to install zend framework on the Ubuntu and i have followed the instruction of installation from 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html 
link but failed to install.

I have downloaded the ZendSkeletonApplication from here
    https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication

After that run of this command

```
php composer.phar self-update   // it's working
```

But after the first command the second Command

```
php composer.phar install   // Not working
```

And showing this error

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

 Problem 1
- zendframework/zendframework 2.3.1 requires php >=5.3.23 -> no matching package found.
- zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0 requires php >=5.3.23 -> no matching package found.
- Installation request for zendframework/zendframework 2.3.* -> satisfiable by zendframework/zendframework[2.3.0, 2.3.1].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.
```

*Update* after some comments:

Now I've downloaded the ZendSkeletonApplication-master and  move the

> Library folder of ZendFramework-2.3.1

in the

> ZendSkeletonApplication-master/vendor/ZF2/

But after that when i access this i'm getting this error on the page

> ZendSkeletonApplication-master/public/index.php // in the browser it showing me this error

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject::offsetGet() must be compatible with
that of ArrayAccess::offsetGet() in /var/www/html/demo/username/ZendSkeletonApplication
-master/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Stdlib/ArrayObject.php on line 22
```

Comment: Problem is clear: ZF2 requires PHP version 5.3.23 or higher, it should be installed on your system. What is the output of php -v command?

Comment: The output of php-v is:- PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Apr  4 2014 01:27:23) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

Comment: @user3611956 So, what have you learned?

Comment: i' m install the php5 and mysql and apache in my computer but not resolved yet .

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: @user3611956, You have change the whole question now. Please post another question when you have other problem to ask.

Comment: You've completely changed the question, but you still have the same problem. The version of PHP that comes with Ubuntu 12.04 is too old to run ZF 2.3. You either need a more recent version of PHP (or a more recent version of Ubuntu), or you need to install ZF 2.2 (which will work with your version) instead.

Comment: Thanx all for your help now the zend framework is installed in my pc the 2.3.1 version not supported , after read the one article i'm download the 2.3.5 and it's working  fine ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well two solutions are possible :

First upgrade php, However it could be possible that Ubuntu release on your system not having upgrades for php. So in that case search google to add APT repository for php 5.3.23 for your ubuntu-VERSION.

Second I personally experienced that, Checkout in folder you will found composer.json file, In that file you will get the settings something like

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.23",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.3.*"
}
```

Just change settings to get other version of ZF2

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.2.*"
}
```

It works for me. It should work for you.

Comment: @user3611956 relying on `"zendframework/zendframework": "2.2.*"` will work. That's the whole point of his post. If it doesn't, there WILL be a different error message.

Comment: @Sam, I think he changed the whole question now.

Comment: Yeah, makes so much sense. If composer download won't work, just download it manually and hope it works. It doesn't change the fact that the PHP Version is still wrong :S

Comment: Thanx **@Sam** for your answer it's work for me but i'cant give you +1 because i'm new and not have the permission so thanx ,thanx ,thanx ,thanx ,thanx ..

Answer (score 0):

Read the error, the main thing we need to focus on is this:
zendframework/zendframework 2.3.1 requires php >=5.3.23 -> no matching package found.

I'll break it down for you.

This states that the package you are attempting to install(zendframework/zendframework 2.3.1) **REQUIRES** a php version **GREATER OR EQUAL TO** 5.3.23.  As your php -v output stated, you are running PHP 5.3.10.  If you are running on a local server that you have access to updating the php version, then update php and run it again, you should see that it works fine.  If you are on a remote server, contact your hosting company and see if they can upgrade you to a newer version of php and then run it again!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you have more then one version of php installed and you have php environment variable linking to an old php executable then you may get this issue. Change your environment variable to the php you want to use.